# How to use Yammer RSS in Microstrategy

Tags: rss, yammer, microstrategy

I am trying to integrate Yammer RSS into Microstrategy Dashboard, but I could not find Yammer RSS feed URL that I can use. Does anybody know the feed URL that can be used in MSTR?

Thank you

Grace

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own widget using SDK? That's the primary option if they don't support Yammer RSS officially.